# Safely getting a subsection of a slice in Go

Tags: go, slice

I know that you can get a subsection of a slice in Go via

```
test := []int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
subsection := test[:2]
```

But if you try something like

```
subsectionError := test[:10]
```

You'll get an out of bounds error. Currently I'm doing something like

```
length := 10
if len(test) < length {
    length = len(test)
}
safeSubsection := test[:length]
```

To avoid the error, but is there a nicer way of doing this? It feels pretty hacky to me, but then again Go generally seems to be a pretty explicit language.

Comment: IMHO that is the way to do it in go. Otherwise "nicer", "hacky", sounds like you are fishing for something, that is primarily opinion based.

Comment: How is checking if you're accessing memory out of bounds "hacky"? This is part of being a memory safe language, and not relying on a SIGSEGV to indicate that you shouldn't be accessing those addresses.

Comment: It's also a rare case that you want some slice of a slice but don't know or care how long the original slice is or whether the resulting slice is the length you requested. I'm guessing this is for truncating a string, in which case I would use `fmt.Sprintf` instead of slicing.

Answer (score 1):

In Go, the answer is often to hide ugliness in a function or method. For example, a min function,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func min(x, y int) int {
    if y < x {
        return y
    }
    return x
}

func main() {
    test := []int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
    fmt.Println(test)
    sub := test[:min(10, len(test))]
    fmt.Println(sub)
}
```

Output:

```
[0 1 2 3 4]
[0 1 2 3 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you find yourself doing this often, and the ugliness annoys you, you can make a slice type instead and put some convenience methods on this. This is useful if you have a lot of convenience methods that operate on a list (say min, max, head, contains etc). I use this to add contains to string or int slices.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Ints []int

func (i Ints) Head(count int) Ints {
    if count > len(i) {
        count = len(i)
    }
    return i[:count]
}


func main() {

    test := Ints{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
    fmt.Printf("First 2 %v\n", test.Head(2))
    fmt.Printf("First 10 %v\n", test.Head(10))
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/OkCjHdlj0u

If you're only doing it once, it's probably not worth the effort, if you have a few loops operating on the same list, it might be. And of course this is one area where it'd be nice to have more sophisticated generic containers in Go.